# Compiling Flexible Collision Library (FCL) with cmake

Tags: cmake, fcl

In my CMakeProject I want to use the flexible collision library (FCL). FCL has dependencies Eigen3 and libccd. So in my CMakeLists.txt I added the git directories of all libraries:

```
add_subdirectory(eigen)
add_subdirectory(libccd)
add_subdirectory(fcl)
```

Building eigen and libccd works just fine without any errors. But fcl can only resolve the dependency for eigen, but not for ccd. That's because flc has a file FindEigen3.cmake, but not for ccd. I wonder how it's supposed to work, because in the original CMakeLists.txt of fcl the line `find_package(ccd QUIET)` results in ccd_FOUND == 0.

I don't think it's causing troubles, but I'm running my cmake project in WSL2 on Windows 10, while using VS Code. The project itself runs on Ubuntu.

I'm still new to cmake, so I wonder if I have to add more information to one of the CMakeLists.txt files or if I have to add some directories to a path variable.

Comment: Generally, the command `find_package` expects the package to be **already installed**. It doesn't work with the package added for build via `add_subdirectory`. Only few of `FindXXX.cmake` scripts explicitly checks whether the package is added via `add_subdirectory` and could work with such package.

Comment: I think my mistake was to think that VS Code handles the installation of the package. Just using```cmake .```, ```make``` and ```sudo make install``` worked as intended